# Setup for using mongoDB through hyper not working

Tags: database, mongodb, command-line-interface, web-development-server, visual-web-developer

I have installed mongoDB successfully and now I am trying to setup it so that I can use it through hyper.
Using hyper terminal in my home directory I have created a file .bash_profile
And by using vim editor I edited it as,

alias mongod = "/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongod.exe"
alias mongo = "/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongo.exe"

and saved it using the cammand :wq! enter.
Now the terminal is showing,

bash: alias: mongod: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: /C/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongod.exe: not found
bash: alias: mongo: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: /C/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongo.exe: not found

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Huh! finally got the solution, removing spaces around the equal sign worked for me.

```
alias mongod="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongod.exe" 
alias mongo="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongo.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

just check your file location and see what are the names of .exe is it Mongo or mongos if it is not the same then correct it

alias mongod="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/6.0/bin/mongod.exe"
alias mongos="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/6.0/bin/mongos.exe"

Remember to change the version accordingly too